# How to get the Id of an object which is added in codebehind using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Example:i am assigning this in .cs page

```
    HiddenField hdnCharacter = new HiddenField();
    HiddenField hdnMaxCharsError = new HiddenField();
    Label lblMaxChrs = new Label();
        lblMaxChrs.ID = "lblMaxchrs";
        hdnMaxCharsError .ID = "hdnMaxCharsError ";
        hdnCharater.ID = "hdnCharater";
```

How to get his ID and values using javascript  in.js file i am trying to do custom control.so i dont have any page to add in aspcontrol. TR

Answer (score 2):

use this way :

```
var id1=document.getElementById('<%= lblMaxchrs.ClientID %>');
var id2=document.getElementById('<%= hdnMaxCharsError.ClientID %>');
var id3=document.getElementById('<%= hdnCharater.ClientID %>');
```

Comment: i tried this way but i cant able to get the object. i am not using aspx or ascx page.i am writing in .js  file. i can able to go to that function but i cant able to get the object

Comment: this way is 90% correct, maybe some thing happen that shows this code with error , put you ode here, in you question

Comment: Hi the space is not enough can u provide me ur mail id

Answer (score 0):

even while you write the asp code. While rendering in the HTML format the field would be hidden but would be present in the  page. you can use :-

```
var id1=document.getElementById('lblMaxchrs');
var id2=document.getElementById('hdnMaxCharsError');
var id3=document.getElementById('hdnCharater');
```

And in order to retrieve the values of each indevidual you can use :-

```
var text1=id1.textContent;
var text2=id2.textContent;
var text3=id3.textContent;
```

Comment: hi friend i tried this too but i cant able to get the object. i am not using aspx or ascx page.i am writing in .js file. i can able to go to that function but i cant able to get the object